# MySql replacing numbers with values giving me issues phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using this query currently

```
UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

I have a field with numbers: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 18, 22, 23, 25, 26, 29, 32, 34, 35, 37, 39 & 40.

The problem that I am running into is that if I use `` UPDATE `Registration`
 SET `name` = replace(`name`, '2', 'jane') `` it replaces the values the have 2 with jane, like I want, but it will also change the fields that have 22 to 2jane, and the same with 32 to 3jane.

How do I make it so that it will only replace the exact value (string) that I input in the query, instead of any field containing that number?

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to violate the first normal form of relational databases and store comma separated lists in a field.

Comment: @VMai It may be a list of possible values.

Comment: For the record, I believe `22` would be replaced by `janejane`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` clause

```
update registration set name = 'jane' where name = '2';
```

Comment: thanks for the help you just saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is as

```
mysql> select replace('32',right('32',1),'jane');
+------------------------------------+
| replace('32',right('32',1),'jane') |
+------------------------------------+
| 3jane                              |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace('2',right('2',1),'jane');
+----------------------------------+
| replace('2',right('2',1),'jane') |
+----------------------------------+
| jane                             |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the query in your case could be as

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET field_name = replace(same_field_name, right(same_field_name,1), 'jane')
```